# Multilabel-indicator is not supported for confusion matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, classification

`multilabel-indicator is not supported` is the error message I get, when trying to run:

`confusion_matrix(y_test, predictions)`

`y_test` is a `DataFrame` which is of shape:

```
Horse | Dog | Cat
1       0     0
0       1     0
0       1     0
...     ...   ...
```

`predictions` is a `numpy array`:

```
[[1, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 0]]
```

I've searched a bit for the error message, but haven't really found something I could apply. Any hints?

Comment: Just wanted to add my two cents for anyone who's looking for the right way to visualize errors of multilabel classifiers: Your prediction array looks like from a **multiclass** classifier. A confusion matrix wouldn't be suitable for **multilabel** classification where multiple labels are predicted at once.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

No, your input to [`confusion_matrix`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html) must be a list of predictions, not OHEs (one hot encodings). Call `argmax` on your `y_test` and `y_pred`, and you should get what you expect.

```
confusion_matrix(
    y_test.values.argmax(axis=1), predictions.argmax(axis=1))

array([[1, 0],
       [0, 2]])
```

Comment: what happened to the third row?

Answer (score 14):

The confusion matrix takes a vector of labels (not the one-hot encoding). You should run

```
confusion_matrix(y_test.values.argmax(axis=1), predictions.argmax(axis=1))
```

Answer (score 6):

If you have numpy.ndarray you can try the following

```py
import seaborn as sns

T5_lables = ['4TCM','WCM','WSCCM','IWCM','CCM']    

ax= plt.subplot()

cm = confusion_matrix(np.asarray(Y_Test).argmax(axis=1), np.asarray(Y_Pred).argmax(axis=1))
sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, fmt='g', ax=ax);  #annot=True to annotate cells, ftm='g' to disable scientific notation

# labels, title and ticks
ax.set_xlabel('Predicted labels');ax.set_ylabel('True labels'); 
ax.set_title('Confusion Matrix'); 
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(T5_lables); ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels(T5_lables);
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

predictions_one_hot = model.predict(test_data)
cm = confusion_matrix(labels_one_hot.argmax(axis=1), predictions_one_hot.argmax(axis=1))
print(cm)
```

Output would be something like this:

```
[[298   2  47  15  77   3  49]
 [ 14  31   2   0   5   1   2]
 [ 64   5 262  22  94  38  43]
 [ 16   1  20 779  15  14  34]
 [ 49   0  71  33 316   7 118]
 [ 14   0  42  23   5 323   9]
 [ 20   1  27  32  97  13 436]]
```