# How to get confusion matrix for binary image?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I'm trying to produce a confusion matrix for 2 binary images. These are extracted (using binary thresholding) from 2 bands in a GeoTiff image, although I think this information should be irrelevant.

```
dataset = rasterio.open('NDBI.tif')

VH_26Jun2015 = dataset.read(1)
VH_30Sep2015 = dataset.read(3)
GND_Truth = dataset.read(7)

VH_diff = VH_26Jun2015 - VH_30Sep2015
ret,th1 = cv2.threshold(VH_diff,0.02,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

print(confusion_matrix(GND_Truth,th1)
```

Error 1: I used the code above and ran into the problem mentioned here [ValueError: multilabel-indicator is not supported for confusion matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52222515/valueerror-multilabel-indicator-is-not-supported-for-confusion-matrix)
I tried the `argmax(axis=1)` solution mentioned in the question and other places, but with a resulting 1983x1983 sized matrix. (This Error 1 is probably same as what the person in the question above ran into).

```
print(confusion_matrix(GND_Truth.argmax(axis=1),th1.argmax(axis=1)))
Output: 
[[8 2 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 ...
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]
```

I checked the contents of the `GND_Truth` and `th1` and verified that they are binary.

```
numpy.unique(GND_Truth)
Output: 
array([0., 1.], dtype=float32)
```

Error 2: Then I tried instead `ravel()` to flatten my binary images when passing to `confusion_matrix` like shown below, but resulting in a 3x3 matrix, whereas I'm expecting a 2x2 matrix.

```
print(confusion_matrix(GND_Truth.ravel().astype(int),th1.ravel().astype(int)))
Output: 
[[16552434        0  2055509]
 [ 6230317        0  1531602]
 [       0        0        0]]
```

Converting the data `astype(int)` did not really make a difference. Can you please suggest what might be causing these 2 errors?